# Python 3.7, pyinstaller: error: argument -d/--debug: invalid choice

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.7

I am trying to export my file, using pyinstaller in debugging mode.
I am using python 3.7, and i encounter this error:
[image]

need help.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
pyinstaller --debug all Sci_cal.py
```

instead.

See the link below:
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3737